# JDownloader API json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, jdownloader

I am using the python API of JDownloader `myjdapi`

With the device.linkgrabber.query_links() I got the following object:

```
{'enabled': True, 'name': 'EQJ_X8gUcAMQX13.jpg', 'packageUUID': 1581524887390, 'uuid': 1581524890696, 'url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/x.jpg?name=orig', 'availability': 'ONLINE'}
```

Now I want to move to the download list with the function:

```
device.linkgrabber.move_to_downloadlist('1581524890696', '1581524887390')
```

The move_to_downloadlist function [(githubrepo)](https://github.com/mmarquezs/My.Jdownloader-API-Python-Library/blob/master/myjdapi/myjdapi.py) says:

```
  def move_to_downloadlist(self, link_ids, package_ids):
        """
        Moves packages and/or links to download list.
        :param package_ids: Package UUID's.
        :type: list of strings.
        :param link_ids: Link UUID's.
        """
        params = [link_ids, package_ids]
        resp = self.device.action(self.url + "/moveToDownloadlist", params)
        return resp
```

But I get always `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

The official API said its a 200 Error, and the reason can be anything.

How I can fix that?

Comment: yea the suggestion is correct

Comment: Okay, so my guess was correct. I've written it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter names are `link_ids` and `package_ids`, that's plural. That would be a good indication that lists are expected here, not single values.

Try this:

```
device.linkgrabber.move_to_downloadlist(['1581524890696'], ['1581524887390'])
```

Comment: thank you. the json error is coming because the communication between myjdownloader and the client api is enctrypted.